# Automatically delete existing git stash when unstashing

Tags: git, netbeans-8, git-stash

I started using git. As I work with different branch between which I sometimes like to change without committing current modifications, I'm using the `stash` function. This works like a charm. My only concern is, that after I `unstash` the stash still keeps existing. Doing this a couple times, it pollutes the branch. Is there a way to automatically remove a `stash` when unstashing it?

**Update**

So I downloaded the source package of netbeans and customized the git module. The only thing to change was a hard coded boolean from false to true for the apply command of a stash, as the whole drop mechanism is already implemented. I loaded the customized module into my netbeans instance and now, when I unstash, the stash automatically gets dropped.

Comment: `git stash pop`?

Comment: Hm yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. Sadly I'm using the Netbeans plugin which does not implement this option. But I guess this question can be marked as solved with your answer.

Comment: So I downloaded the source package of netbeans and customized the git module. The only thing to change was a hard coded boolean from `false` to `true` for the `apply` command of a stash. I loaded the customized module into my netbeans instance and now, when I unstash, the stash automatically gets dropped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should run:

```
git stash pop
```

See the [man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#git-stash-pop--index-q--quietltstashgt):

> `pop [--index] [-q|--quiet] [<stash>]`
>
> **Remove** a single stashed state
>   from the stash list and apply it on top of the current working tree
>   state, i.e., do the inverse operation of git stash save. The working
>   directory must match the index.

If you don't want to remove the state, you should use:

```
git stash apply
```

See [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#git-stash-apply--index-q--quietltstashgt) for details.